# compiler error: operator "*"and"+" cannot be applied

Tags: c#, winforms, algorithm

i asked like this question yesterday but i didnt get good answer about it

in the code below why i cant use * and + in last line?and whats the way to solve that?thanks

```
    private void bigzarb(int u,int v)
    {
        double n;
        int x=0;
        int y;
        int w=0;
        int z;
        string[] i = textBox7.Text.Split(',');
        int[] nums = new int[i.Length];
        for (int counter = 0; counter < i.Length; counter++)
        {
            nums[counter] = Convert.ToInt32(i[counter]);
        }

        u = nums[0];
        double firstdigits =Math.Floor(Math.Log10(u) + 1);
         v = nums[1];
        double seconddigits = Math.Floor(Math.Log10(v) + 1);
        if (firstdigits >= seconddigits)
        {
            n = firstdigits;

        }
        else
        {
            n = seconddigits;

        }
        if (u == 0 || v == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("the Multiply is 0");
        }
        string threshold = textBox9.Text;
        int intthreshold = Convert.ToInt32(threshold);
        int intn = Convert.ToInt32(n);
        if (intn <= intthreshold)
        {

            double uv = u * v;
            string struv = uv.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(struv);

        }
        else
        {
           int m  =Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(n / 2));

            x = u % 10 ^ m;
            y = u / 10 ^ m;
            w = v % 10 ^ m;
            z = v / 10 ^ m;

            bigzarb(x, w) *( 10 ^ m) +(bigzarb(x,w)+bigzarb(w,y))*10^m +bigzarb(y,z);///compiler gives error operator "*"and"+" cannot be applied to operands of type'void'and'int'

///and compiler gives error operator "*"and"+" cannot be applied to operands of type 'void' and 'void'
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jon Skeet has answered this question, but I though I would be more explicit to explain exactly what is happening on this line...

```
bigzarb(x, w) *( 10 ^ m) + (bigzarb(x,w)+bigzarb(w,y))*10^m +bigzarb(y,z);
```

Let's break it into sections

The first statement is

```
bigzarb(x, w)
```

But as you'll see from Jon's answer - you are not returning a value from this method...

private void bigzarb(int u,int v)

Now let's replace that bit with it's actual value now we've explained it:

```
[void] *( 10 ^ m) + (bigzarb(x,w)+bigzarb(w,y))*10^m +bigzarb(y,z);
```

The same goes for all of the other calls to bigzarb - so let's replace those too...

```
[void] * ( 10 ^ m) + ([void] + [void]) * 10 ^ m + [void];
```

So your problem is, in order to use mathematical operators, you need numbers on each side - but you don't have numbers because your method is void.

You could change your method to return a number - but be aware of recursion... when you call this method, it calls itself three times and each of those calls will result in a further three calls to the method. Not good!

Comment: wow,you explained clearly,now i should certainly define return?because i wanted to use this code in button event handler and there cant we use return

Comment: thanks so much,i will ask other question about implement with return

Answer (score 5):

Well, there are a few things wrong here:

- You're trying to use the *results* of calling a method, but that method has no return value... so there's no result to multiply. This is what the compiler is complaining about.
- I suspect you think that ^ performs a "power" operation - it's actually a bitwise `xor`
- Your final statement doesn't actually *do* anything with the results of the calculation

Given that your method doesn't return anything, what values do you think are going to be used in an expression such as `bigzarb(x, w) *( 10 ^ m)`?

Comment: thanks,i thought ^ is power,whats the symbol of power?in bigzarb(x,w) i want to replace the value of u with x and the value of v with w,and then multiply with 10^m,how can i do that?thanks

Comment: @Arash You can use Math.Power function.

Comment: @arash: There's no symbol of power - use `Math.Pow` instead. You're still not really making any sense though - using `bigzarb(x, w)` in an expression means "invoke the `bigzarb` method, and use its result for the rest of the calculation" - but `bigzard` doesn't *have* a result, because it's void. *What value are you trying to multiply?*

Comment: thanks master,i understood,now i implement with return i have aproblem with it,i will ask other question,thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Your method `bigzarb` has a void signature, which you are using in a calulation.

Answer (score 0):

this is because

rerturn type  of  function gzarb(x, w) is void  so you can't do any operatin on a void pointer.

and in the last line ,you are using output of gzarb in a runing calculation.

Comment: It's not a "null pointer" - I think bringing pointers into the picture is going to confuse more than it helps.

Comment: It's not a "void pointer" either.  It's not *any* kind of *pointer* at all.