# Problem with return in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, algorithm

Because of asking my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487755/compiler-error-operator-and-cannot-be-applied), I've changed my code to use `return`. I always have this problem with return: I know I should use return (where I comment in code below) but I dont know how should I define it to work? Thanks for your help.

```
public double bigzarb(int u, int v)
{
    double n;
    int x=0;
    int y;
    int w=0;
    int z;
    string[] i = textBox7.Text.Split(',');
    int[] nums = new int[i.Length];
    for (int counter = 0; counter < i.Length; counter++)
    {
        nums[counter] = Convert.ToInt32(i[counter]);
    }

    u = nums[0];
    double firstdigits =Math.Floor(Math.Log10(u) + 1);
    v = nums[1];
    double seconddigits = Math.Floor(Math.Log10(v) + 1);
    if (firstdigits >= seconddigits)
    {
        n = firstdigits;
    }
    else
    {
        n = seconddigits;
    }
    if (u == 0 || v == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("the Multiply is 0");
    }
    string threshold = textBox9.Text;
    int intthreshold = Convert.ToInt32(threshold);
    int intn = Convert.ToInt32(n);
    if (intn <= intthreshold)
    {
        double uv = u * v;
        string struv = uv.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(struv);
        ///i know here should be a return but i dont know how to define it to work
    }
    else
    {
        int m = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(n / 2));

        x = u % 10 ^ m;
        y = u / 10 ^ m;
        w = v % 10 ^ m;
        z = v / 10 ^ m;

        return  bigzarb(x, w) *Math.Pow(10,m) +(bigzarb(x,w)+bigzarb(w,y))*Math.Pow(10,m) +bigzarb(y,z);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is here. There can be more than one return..

Comment: Your method is declared as `void` but seems to return a `double` or `Decimal`.

Comment: i wrote bad in writing code here,i edited code,now whats the problem

Comment: "according to my last question" - you might try and provide a link to that one ...

Comment: "what should I return" - please provide a description of what you want to achieve, any error messages you want to get rid of and other problems you want to have solved.

Comment: now the error is:not all code paths return a value

Comment: please see my comment in code

Comment: arash, if the value of uv is what you want to have in if(), just write return uv; under your comment

Comment: @Pabuc:i wrote: x = u % Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(10),Convert.ToDouble(m));  but it says cannot convert double to int,whats the problem?thanks

Comment: now i just have a simple question that is not related to this,now how can i call this method in button click?when the use cick button this method call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

arash, your problem isn't with that return, your problem is `bigzarb()` is declared as void which means it has no returning value yet you use it in your last line as `bigzarb(x,w) * ....` which will give you an error. Also, since you declared your bigzarb() as void, you cant return a value in it. Also ^ doesn't mean power of in .net, you should use `Math.Power` instead.

Edit: You should change your method from `void bigzarb()` to `double bigzarb()` and replace ^ with Math.Power and retry to see if yit works.

Last edit: Change your method return type to double from int and change the last line to:

```
return bigzarb(x, w) * Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(10), Convert.ToDouble(m)) + (bigzarb(x, w) + bigzarb(w, y)) * Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(10), Convert.ToDouble(m)) + bigzarb(y, z);
```

Comment: and take the return... outside of the else (2 lines under) so that all paths can return the value..

Comment: x = u % 10 ^ m; // you should also change these lines to math.pow() or it will do or operation like Jon said on the other topic

Comment: return shouldnt take outside because in else condition it should work

Comment: @Pabuc:i wrote: x = u % Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(10),Convert.ToDouble(m));  but it says cannot convert double to int,whats the problem?thanks

Comment: x = u % Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(10),Convert.ToDouble(m))); should work

Answer (score 1):

If your method is defined to "return void", you can't return some value.
So change that "void" into "int" or "double", whatever type of value you want to return.

The next question is what value do you want to return in that spot? Return that.

By the way: if you really don't want to return a value (ever!) then that "void" is correct and you should only use "return" without value (or let the method run until the last line of the method).

Comment: @arash: now you have defined your code to return an "int" - good. That means that every "return" should provide an int value. What value should be correct in that situation? (**I** don't know what your method should do, **you** do)

Answer (score 1):

```
    public int bigzarb(int u, int v)
    {
        double n;
        int x = 0;
        int y;
        int w = 0;
        int z;
        string[] i = textBox1.Text.Split(',');
        int[] nums = new int[i.Length];
        for (int counter = 0; counter < i.Length; counter++)
        {
            nums[counter] = Convert.ToInt32(i[counter]);
        }

        u = nums[0];
        double firstdigits = Math.Floor(Math.Log10(u) + 1);
        v = nums[1];
        double seconddigits = Math.Floor(Math.Log10(v) + 1);
        if (firstdigits >= seconddigits)
        {
            n = firstdigits;

        }
        else
        {
            n = seconddigits;

        }
        if (u == 0 || v == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("the Multiply is 0");
        }
        //string threshold = textBox9.Text;
        int intthreshold = Convert.ToInt32(textBox9.Text);//Edited by me
        int intn = Convert.ToInt32(n);
        if (intn <= intthreshold)
        {

            double uv = u * v;
            string struv = uv.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(struv);
            ///i know i should use return here but how can i implement that to work?
        }
        else
        {
            int m = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(n / 2));

            x = u % 10 ^ m;
            y = u / 10 ^ m;
            w = v % 10 ^ m;
            z = v / 10 ^ m;

            return bigzarb(x, w) * (10 ^ m) + (bigzarb(x, w) + bigzarb(w, y)) * 10 ^ m + bigzarb(y, z);
        }
        return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Plz tell us " string[] i = textBox7.Text.Split(',');" what kind of values are here in textbox7

Answer (score 1):

my tip to you is to structure your code, extract some of the code to separate functions with meaningful names and also rename your variables to sometging meaningful. That would make it easier to read, understand and you get a better "flow" in your code. Also, you should complement your text with an actual question. Try to insert an extra return statement in the if code block, it is perfectly fine to have multiple return statements.

```
if(logic check)
{
     return something;
}
else
{
     return something else;
}
```

You need to have return either in both statements or one return after the if-else block, otherwise you'll get somekind of compiler error saying that not all code paths returns a result or something similar.

Comment: You can just add an extra return statement, as my example suggest. Or you can also take your return statement in the else part and put it after the if else block. But really, your code looks sort of weird. Why do you want a function that calculates a value and shows a message box, you should try to make an effort in refactoring the code so it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You have only one return and it's a recursive call (calling itself) --> **stack overflow!** You need to have another return somewhere without a recursive call

Comment: you could just do "return uv;"

Answer (score 0):

Its a confusing one.since your function contains Void as return type

Answer (score 0):

Declare the integer variable for returning the values
Ex:

```
 public int func()
{
 int l_nData  = 0;

if(condition)
{
  l_nData = 1;
  return l_nData;
}
else
{
  l_nData = 2;
  return l_nData;
 }
 return l_nData;
```

}